# Need a regex for phrase including spaces in between, but not spaces to the right?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a logfile, where we parse each line using regex in Python.

Part of each line contains a phrase, which is one or more words.

For example, in the below, the phrase is "SOME PHRASE".

```
12-09-95 10:37:46,082 [3] INFO Foobar <> - 1995-Dec-09 10:37:47.189025 --- [5571467078570868736::TYPE    ::SOME PHRASE ::1995-Dec-09 10:37:47.165672::1995-Dec-09 10:37:47.188790::00:00:00.023117]
```

In other lines, it may only be a single word, for example "PHRASE".

```
12-09-95 10:37:46,082 [3] INFO Foobar <> - 1995-Dec-09 10:37:47.189025 --- [5571467078570868736::TYPE    ::SOME PHRASE    ::1995-Dec-09 10:37:47.165672::1995-Dec-09 10:37:47.188790::00:00:00.023117]
```

We need to extract all the words of the phrase, including any spaces in between words, but minus any whitespace either to the left or right of it.

The phrase itself is easy - the relevant part of our regex:

```
::(?P<phrase>[\w\s]+)::
```

However, I'm not sure how to discard the whitespace on the right using regex - the logfile usually have a bunch of extraneous spaces after the phrase we want.

I know I could just use str.rstrip() to remove it afterwards, but I'd rather use the regex expression itself to simply not pick it up - is there a way of doing this?

Cheers,
Victor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not match trailing whitespace like so..

```
::(?P<phrase>[\w\s]+?)\s*::
```

Comment: @Kobi: Thanks, will fix that.

Comment: heya,I just tried, it's still picking up extraneous spaces after the phrase. E.g., it will give "SOME PHRASE    " instead of "SOME PHRASE".

Comment: You should have a sub match "SOME PHRASE". Alternatively, try ::(?P<phrase>[\w\s]+?)(?:\s*)::

Comment: @Leif: Hmm, that seems to have worked - is there any chance you could explain to me how it works?

Comment: If a sub expression starts with "?:" it is not captured. It's easier for you then to get what you wanted. I don't know how python returns matches but I guess it is a multidimensional array which allows you to access any sub matches. You just need to know the indices. If you print out the array you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

why to use regex?

```
>>> line = "12-09-95 10:37:46,082 [3] INFO Foobar <> - 1995-Dec-09 10:37:47.189025 --- [5571467078570868736::TYPE    ::SOME PHRASE ::1995-Dec-09 10:37:47.165672::1995-Dec-09 10:37:47.188790::00:00:00.023117]"
>>> line.split('::')[2].strip()
'SOME PHRASE'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> p = re.compile('::\s*(?P<phrase>(?:\w[\w\s]*)?\w)\s*::')
>>> p.findall(': test :: test test :: ::  s  :: ::  another test:: ::third test   ::')
['test test', 's', 'another test', 'third test']
```

this works by ensuring the phrase starts and ends with a \w (even if there's only one \w). Leif's also does, I see, but I can't explain how his works without more effort than I'm willing to put into it (sleepy)...